# Open Youtube link using the system app or the external browser

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have cordova 5.4.0 and I need to open a Youtube URL like this: `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=example` making user to choose between the Youtube system app (iOS, Android etc...) or any external browser.
Is it possibile to do that using the InAppBrowser plugin or even without it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is  possible

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {  
        var url="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=example"   
        openUrl(url);
    }
    //for launch  website
    function openUrl(url){
       //opens inapp browser
        window.open(url,'_self');
       //opens system browser
        window.open(url,'_system');
    }
```

Comment: it does not ask to open the external youtube app